# Rails jQuery Datatables, order by defined/calculated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I have a Model that has a `num_likes` and `num_views` attributes.

The following will work to order them

```
@models = Model.all ## this may not be "all" so I dont want to use scope
@models.order({'num_likes': 'desc'})
```

if I defined the method

```
def like_pct
    num_likes / num_views
end
```

Then the jQuery DT does not correctly order by this since it's not in the DB.

How can I order by this attr?

Here is the actual controller code:

```
    @pages = some_filtered_pages_collection

    # Sort based on requested column
    params[:order].each do |i, order|
      column = order[:column]
      sort_column = params[:columns][column][:data] # This is the attr name being sorted
      sort_order = order[:dir] # asc or desc
      @pages = @pages.order([[sort_column, sort_order]].to_h)
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could just switch from using ActiveRecord's `order` method to using native Ruby's `sort` method, it's probably a better idea to have the DB server doing the work rather than the Rails server.

Since your like_pct method is only defined in the Rails server and the DB server, obviously we won't be able to use that method to accomplish this.

So here's how I would approach it.  Please note that I'm assuming here you are using a PostgreSQL server, I don't know if this will work for your particular SQL dialect.

```
params[:order].each do |i, order|
      column = order[:column]
      sort_column = params[:columns][column][:data] # This is the attr name being sorted
      sort_column = '(num_likes / num_views)' if sort_column = 'like_pct'
      sort_order = order[:dir] # asc or desc
      @pages = @pages.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_order}")
    end
```

Note that for this to work you'll need to change the order method from using hash syntax to string syntax, otherwise ActiveRecord will translate the query to `ORDER BY pages.(num_likes / num_views)...` which clearly won't work.